# What is a loding?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-terms

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_v_Mountford) quotes Street v Mountford as follows:

> ‘the landlord is there for the purpose of being able, as landlords commonly do in the case of lodings, to have his own servants to look after the house and the

What are lodings? Is it simply a typo for lodgings? If so, then what is the source of this mistake and how far back can it be traced? Did some official source publish the judgment with this error?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this sems to be only a typo, not a legal issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A copy of the source material is hosted by the British and Irish Legal Information Institute: *Street v Mountford*, [[1985] UKHL 4](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKHL/1985/4.html).

I quote the portion showing that the spelling used in the source is "lodgings":

> ... as landlords commonly do in the case of lodgings ...